# How to solve NuGet error when tried to browse new references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

When trying to browse references from Nuget package manager in Visual studio 2015 I am facing the below error:

```
[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source 
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

---

Recently I have updated my VS2015 after that I am facing this error before the update I didn't get any errors when adding references.
I found some answers based on the issue and tried

1. I have uninstalled Nuget and reinstalled.
2. Deleted NuGet.config file

But my issue was not solved, finally I have uninstalled VS2015 and reinstalled but still I am facing the same error.
Can any one solve my issue please?

Comment: i have changed package source to "https"://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json to "http"://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json then i am able to see the references but unable to install them when i tried to install it showing error An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Selenium.WebDriver.2.53.1' from source 'NuGet'.

Comment: According to the error message, this issue seems caused by the network access the nuget.org. You can try access the url from browser to check whether it can be accessed from browser directly.

Comment: in my office system i have checked the url in browser directly it shows this site can't be reached but the same url tried in my personnel computer i didn't get any errors and also i have installed nuget packages in VS2015 from my pc but not from the office system.

Answer (score 2):

Since the you could not open the url in browser directly from your office system, there should be some internet limitations in your office environment. I suggest you contact your office IT to confirm whether they add any limitations and whether used any proxy. If they are using some proxy, you need to set the proxy settings in NuGet.Config file which store in C:\Users\user name\AppData\Roaming\NuGet as below settings. Detailed information please refer to the Proxy settings part in [this link](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings).

```
<add key="http_proxy" value="host" />
<add key="http_proxy.user" value="username" />
<add key="http_proxy.password" value="encrypted_password" />
```